# How to wait for element to be visible for Mobile app in QuaMotion

Tags: selenium, mobile, automation

Anyone know "How to wait for element to be visible for Mobile app in QuaMotion".

I wonder if anyone has used Quamotion for automation of mobile app.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product manager of Quamotion here.

We implement the Selenium/WebDriver protocol, so you can use the same commands you'd use to wait for an element in Quamotion as you'd do in Selenium.

It depends a bit on which client you are using (C#, PowerShell, Java,...) but the construct is always the same.

For example, in PowerShell, you can use the `Wait-ForElement` command to which you can pass an XPath expression, a marked statement or a class name.

If you'd want to wait for an element with the text `Login`, you can use this command:

`Wait-Element -marked 'Login'`

This will block your script until this element is visible.

If you're using another programming language, let me know, and I'll update my answer.